Sleuth ParentSpanId is null in logs
I am using sleuth in our old spring boot application. When I was checking logs traceId and spanId is visible but parentSpanId is null.
But paresntSpanId is getting passed into header as X-B3-ParentSpanId.
Can anyone please guide how to display the value of X-B3-ParentSpanId in log statement too. And is there a way to set custom value to it.
